# Safely remove USB from batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, usb

Can a batch file be made in windows that could safely eject  the USB?So far on various sites there exist different utilities like devcon.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/637854/safely-remove-a-usb-drive-using-bat-file

Comment: [This is not possible in a batch script using builtin utils](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/ITCG/thread/964f7d82-8810-4c18-93a3-0e5de1a3f006). So you have to use one of those third party utils. Otherwise use powershell as suggested by Nath.

Answer (score 5):

`Eject Media and Remove Drive`
Freeware by Uwe Sieber - http://www.uwe-sieber.de

Remove drive is what you need for USB safe removal.

Answer (score 3):

Download RemoveDrive.exe from http://www.uwe-sieber.de/drivetools_e.html

and then use the code below.

> removedrive\x64\RemoveDrive.exe F: -L

Note that

- F: is the drive you want to eject
- -L means Loop

Answer (score 2):

Please try this script to safely remove disk, maybe useful to you :)

```
@echo off
cls

set tempfile="%TEMP%\tmp_disk.dsk"
cd  %SystemRoot%\system32
echo.
echo   ...:: Safely Remove Disk ::...
echo.
echo   Select the disk volume number (if the disk has multiple volumes, select any of them)
echo.
echo.
echo list volume | diskpart | findstr /C:Volume /C:---
echo.
set /p volume="   Selected volume: "
echo.

echo select volume %volume% >>%tempfile%
echo offline disk >>%tempfile%
echo online disk >>%tempfile%

diskpart /s %tempfile% | findstr /C:"not valid"

if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" (
  echo   Disk has been unlocked successfully.  Try to safely remove it now...
  pause
)

del /F %tempfile%
```

Comment: Nice idea, but it seems to fail. Tested with Win7x64. Got an error message `The process isn't supported for removable media` (translated)

Comment: Hmm... this's interesting...
I've tested it on windows and any usbdrive like flashdisk, external hardrive, it work fine. 
Can you provide more information about your usb stick you've tested it ?

Comment: I tested with a `Cruzer Blade 32GB` from SanDisk

Comment: I've tested it too but another SanDisk product. You can use this script if your usb get locked in process handler. :)

Answer (score 1):

While you can use powershell. 
Try the following:

```
public string GenerateScript(string driveLetter)
    {
        return "$vol = get-wmiobject -Class Win32_Volume | where{$_.Name -eq '" + driveLetter + :\\'};\n" +  
               "$vol.DriveLetter = $null\n" +  
               "$vol.Put()\n" +  
               "$vol.Dismount($false, $false)\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try with [ejectjs.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/ejectjs.bat) - it does not require external binaries.

```
Example usage:
::eject drive
call ejectjs.bat G
::eject all applicable drives
call ejectjs.bat *
```