# delayed usb stick removal after close application running from USB

Tags: c#, usb, delayed-execution

I have this program in C# VS2005 for copying files from and to an USB stick

since it's going to be used in a embedded Windows with only touch screen it loads from the usb as an "autorun.exe" (executed as the "detected usb drive" dialog shows),  no installation to run from hard drive is allowed.

I cannot eject drive in use, since it is running from there, is there a way to make the exe end the Form and then execute my "RemoveDrive" function  after all the execution ended?

Here is my code:

```
  private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.Close();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        RemoveDriveTools.RemoveDrive(discz);
    }
```

this get the same error as if the program still opened

"discz" has the letter drive assigned "F:"

RemoveDriveTools.RemoveDrive

is the metod to eject drive.

Thank for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my recommendation:

This cannot be done in code because while the program is executing, the system is locked.  I recommend one of two approaches to task this:

1. Start up the program with or without a flag.
   a.  When the program starts without the flag, it copies itself to another directory off of the thumb drive (and any required DLLs) (think temp directory), and starts THAT version of the program with the flag enabled.
   b.  The flag enabled version will run and due to the flag will know its not running from the drive.
2. Run from the thumb drive as normal.  Upon exit of the program start a batch file which will:
   a.  Have a pause to ensure the program as truly exited.
   b.  Run a command line to close the thumb drive.  ([Safely remove USB from batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22705830/safely-remove-usb-from-batch-file))

Go with option 1, its easier.  That will enforce the "normal" execution of your program runs from the temp area instead of the thumb drive.